# Vue template does not update when pinia store state changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I'm in the process of migrating a Vue 2 app to Vue 3. It's gone well enough to this point, except that templates aren't updating based on Pinia state. I've looked at other SO questions related to this, but I can't resolve this problem.

Here are my components (parent and child) and store - Note, I'm using the options API

```
// Parent
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ActionButtonGroup />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useActionStore } from '@/stores/ActionStore';
import ActionButtonGroup from './components/ActionButtonGroup/main.vue';
export default {
  name: 'ActionsParent'
  components: {
    ActionButtonGroup,
  },
  created() {
    this.loadActions();
  },
  methods: {
    loadActions() {
      useActionStore().loadActions();
    },
  }
}
```

```
// Child
<template>
  <div class="action-buttons d--f ai--c">
      <Spinner class="ml-3" v-if="loading" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'pinia';
import { useActionStore } from '@/stores/ActionStore';
import { Spinner } from '@/components/index';

export default {
  name: 'ActionButtonGroup',
  components: {
    Spinner,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useActionStore, ['loading']),
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// Store
import { ActionApi } from '@/api/index';
export const useActionStore = defineStore('Action', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      loading: false,
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async loadActions() {
      this.loading = true;
      await this.fetchActions();
      this.loading = false;
    },
    async fetchActions(id) {
      const actions = await ActionApi.fetchActions();
      return actions;
    },
  }
}
```

I've also tried using a setup function in the child, but that doesn't resolve the problem:

```
setup() {
    const store = useActionStore();
    const loading  = computed(() => store.loading);
    return {
      loading
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I can't comment on this, so my response has to be an answer.

I don't think the problem has to do with Pinia. I checked and recreated it, and things are fine. I suggest looking into other areas, such as your Vue instance and the function itself that is being called. Try slowly removing things to bare bones to see if it'll work. You'll also want to confirm that after your "await" function "fetchActions" is called, it actually finishes, and the state updates.

If the state is updating, then you know it has to be related to the Vue instance. You could then try rebuilding in another Vue instance to help narrow down the issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply :). Pinia state is updated as expected, so I'll take your advice and and start stripping things out to see if I can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Josh, glad to hear it; that'll help narrow things down. Let me know if anything else comes up!